# If NA appears in a vector, make all subsequent elements NA

Tags: r, na

Once an initial NA appears in a vector, I would like to replace all subsequent values in that vector with NA.

For instance, if `x = c(0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 1, 2)`

I desire: `x = c(0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)`

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could do:

```
x <- ifelse(cumsum(is.na(x)) > 0, NA, x)
```

Or faster:

```
x[cumsum(is.na(x)) > 0] <- NA
```

Output:

```
[1]  0  0 NA NA NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
v <- c(0,0, NA, 0, 0, 1, 2)
v[ as.logical(cummax(is.na(v))) ] <- NA
v
# [1]  0  0 NA NA NA NA NA
```

One could also use

```r
v[ dplyr::cumany(is.na(v)) ] <- NA
```